# python regex boolean statement not working

Tags: python, regex

My problem is that this simple regex statement with a boolean operator only gives me the result I want when the first item on the left side of the bitwise operator | is present in the sentence. Could someone tell me why it isn't working on the alternative as well?

```
 import re

 b = 'this is a good day to die hard'

 jeff = re.search('good night (.+)hard|good day (.+)hard', b)

 print jeff.group(1)
```

Comment: Because the second `(...)` creates the second group.

Comment: The proper name for `|` is in a regular expression is "alternation." It's not really Boolean.

Answer (score 1):

You have two sets of capturing parentheses - therefore you have two numbered capturing groups. If the second branch matches, the `group(1)` will be set to None, and `group(2)` will contain that which was matched by the second group.

---

There are several ways to fix this. One would be to write so that there is just one group, for example

```
jeff = re.search('good (?:day|night) (.+)hard', b)
```

Answer (score 0):

The second `(...)` creates the second capturing group that you need to access with `.group(2)`.

You may write a regex that will capture `day` or `night`, and the second group will fetch all up to the last `hard`.

```
import re
b = 'this is a good day to die hard'
jeff = re.search('good (day|night) (.+)', b)
if jeff:
    print jeff.group(1)
    print jeff.group(2)
```

Output of the [demo](http://ideone.com/U4wDdI):

```
day
to die hard
```